# Interesting integral involving $\Gamma (z)$.

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function

Find the value of $$\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-\lambda t \cos(\theta)} \cos(\lambda t \sin (\theta)) dt$$ where $\lambda >0$, $x>0$, and ${-1\over 2}\pi < \theta < {1\over 2}\pi$ in terms of the Gamma function.

I'm assuming this requires at least two different substitutions in order to evaluate it.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, when $\Re{(a)}>0$,

$$\int_0^{\infty} dt \, t^{x-1} \, e^{-a t} = \frac{\Gamma(x)}{a^x}$$

Note that the above integral may be written as

$$\Re{\left [\int_0^{\infty} dt \, t^{x-1} \, e^{-\lambda t e^{i \theta}} \right ]} $$

Therefore, as $\cos{\theta}>0$, the integral is

$$\Re{\left [\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\left( \lambda e^{i \theta}\right )^x} \right ]} = \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\lambda^x} \cos{(x \theta)}$$

Comment: To prove that more formally, you could integrate $f(z) = z^{x-1}e^{- \lambda z}$ around a wedge in the first quadrant that makes an angle of $\theta$ with the positive real axis and is indented at the origin.

Comment: @RandomVariable: wedge is for Gaussian term.  My result is valid because of the constraint on $\theta$.

Comment: @RandomVariable: I'm saying there is no need for it.  And have you worked it out?  I'm also telling you that there are no convergence issues here, and nothing more formal is necessary.

Comment: It's an example used in several complex analysis textbooks.  But the Laplace transform is valid for $\text{Re}(a) >0$.  So it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x - 1}\,\,
\expo{-\lambda t\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\,
\cos\pars{\lambda t\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x - 1}\,\,
\expo{-\lambda t\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\,
\expo{\ic\lambda t\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\color{red}{x} - 1}\,\,
\expo{-\lambda zt}\,\dd t\,\right\vert_{\,z\ =\ \exp\pars{-\ic\theta}}
\end{align}
Note that
$\ds{\expo{-\lambda zt} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-\lambda zt}^{k} \over k!} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\pars{\lambda z}^{k}}\,\,{\pars{-t}^{k} \over k!}}$.

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x - 1}\,\,
\expo{-\lambda t\cos\pars{\theta}}\,\,
\cos\pars{\lambda t\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd t}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\bracks{\Gamma\pars{\color{red}{x}}
\pars{\lambda z}^{-\color{red}{x}}}\quad
\pars{\substack{\ds{Ramanujan's}\\[1mm] \ds{Master}
\\[1mm] \ds{Theorem}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\Gamma\pars{x}\lambda^{-x}\,\,
\Re\bracks{\pars{\expo{-\ic\theta}}^{-x}} =
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{x}\lambda^{-x}\cos\pars{\theta x}} \\ &
\end{align}